# @future to reduce number of Soql Queries

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, future

Say Suppose I'm having 150 Records in a Custom object and I will display 100 records in a Vf page.When I select all the records and process then what happens is based on criteria,these fields will Insert into

- Contacts,Opportunities,Accounts,Cases etc
- Custom object1,object2,object3 & so on

For this a global controller is their and I will call those methods in my controller class.
Now here what my problem is When I select say 50 records & process, the queries in the method of a global controller are also called(I haven't wrote Query in for loop) for each Record.Say suppose their are 5 Queries in the global class.So when i process 50 Records 50*5 = 250.

I think we can handle this by using @future Annatotation.I dont have much idea on this. Any Help on this please

Comment: Think about bulkyfing your logic so that your DML statements are limited to a single insert/update per object type.

Comment: @Sdry I'm not having any problem with the DML Statements as I'll add to a list & insert them only once in my controller.The problem is with the global controller methods which I'll cal in my class.In global controller class  they are 10 methods  and in my class I'll cal 5 methods which consists of Queries.I'll cal this methods in a for loop which I can't avoid it

Comment: Why can't you avoid it? You may need to rewrite that code.

Comment: You are subject to the following limitations with @future methods:
**-No more than 10 method calls per Apex invocation**
**-200 method calls per full Salesforce user license or Force.com App Subscription user license, per 24 hours**

Comment: I'll be processing only 100 Records at a time and by using @future I guess I can resolve this by adding 10 method calls per Apex invocation at a time to avoid the limit of Soql Query

Comment: @PJC hmm yes.Any example for my requirement by using future

Comment: I'd add an additional concern that's not been mentioned by others. Since you plan to actually display these records in a VF page, using @future could have implications on what happens to your ViewState. This could potentially cause problems for you with the page and is something I recommend you look at.

Answer (score 3):

It difficult to determine if you're asking about DML or queries, but what you're asking for is bulkification of one of the two. Right?

Here is a good example of how to bulkify for queries ([source](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/04/20/writing-bulk-triggers-for-salesforce/)). This code finds the favourite colour for an owner of an Account and then sets it on a custom field on that account:

```
trigger AddOwnerColor on Account (before insert, before update) {

    // create a set of all the unique ownerIds
    Set<id> ownerIds = new Set<id>();
    for (Account a : Trigger.new)
        ownerIds.add(a.OwnerId);   

    // query for all the User records for the unique userIds in the records
    // create a map for a lookup / hash table for the user info
    Map<id, User> owners = new Map<id, User>([Select Favorite_Color__c from User Where Id in :ownerIds]);  

    // iterate over the list of records being processed in the trigger and
    // set the color before being inserted or updated
    for (Account a : Trigger.new)
        a.Owner_Favorite_Color__c = owners.get(a.OwnerId).Favorite_Color__c;

}
```

Note that as a rule you should have as close to only 1 query per object as possible. There are exceptions but you should keep this as your guiding principle.

For DML you should be adding each object record to a list of it's type, and then inserting/updating them all at once:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = Map<Id, Account>([SELECT id, name, department FROM Account LIMIT 100]);
Map<Id, Custom__c> customObjs = Map<Id, Custom__c>([SELECT id FROM Custom__c WHERE account__c IN :accounts.keyset()];

List<Custom__c> updatedCustomObjs = new List<Custom__c>();

for(Id cId: customObjs.keyset()) {
 Custom__c c = customObjs.get(cId);
 Account a = account.get(c.account__c);

 c.department = a.department;
 updatedCustomObjs.add(c);
} 

insert updatedCustomObjs;
```

Note that here your guiding principle is to have as close to one DML statement per object types as possible.

Comment: I'll be processing only 100 Records at a time and by using @future I guess I can resolve this by adding 10 method calls per Apex invocation at a time to avoid the limit of Soql Query

Comment: This might solve your problem now but it's not the best practice in this case (unless I've missed something). Note that if your processing requirement becomes bigger in the future you might get stuck again!